# haml + rails3 + with_options broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml

I've decided to move my rails2 project to rails3 (and ruby 1.9.2). I have such template:

```
%table
  %thead
    - I18n.with_options :scope => [:activerecord, :attributes, :segment] do |i18n|
      %tr 
        %th= i18n.t :name                                                                                                     
        %th= i18n.t :network
        %th= i18n.t :vlan
        %th 
  %tbody
    ...something here...
```

It works fine on rails2 in both development and production modes. But on rails 3.0.3 and haml 3.0.25 production mode generates incorrect html: http://pastebin.com/mJLk8sSs, 'table' tag appears twice (and thead repeated twice as well).

In development mode html is correct. It's also correct in production if I set 'ugly' haml option to false.

Comment: How does your html example look like its done with 'ugly' option set to true?

Comment: Heikki, see pastebin link above. It's production mode, which has 'ugly' set true by default.

Comment: I don't follow.. :) "It's also correct in production if I set 'ugly' haml option to true". Did you mean "to false"?

Comment: Ah, sorry. To false, updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed in rails 3.0.2 (only using erb as far as I can tell)

see: https://rails.lighthouseapp.com/projects/8994/tickets/4429-templates-that-use-with_options

It appears to still be broken using rails 3.0.3 with haml 3.0.25.  There has been some talk on the haml mailing list about it, though I don't think anything has been done yet.

(http://osdir.com/ml/haml/2010-08/msg00107.html)

To solve this issue I have simply removed with_options from my templates.  You could alternatively assign your options to a variable and pass that to each call of `t`.

```
 - i18n_options = {:scope => [:activerecord, :attributes, :segment]}
 %tr 
    %th= t :name,    i18n_options                                           
    %th= t :network, i18n_options
    %th= t :vlan,    i18n_options
```

Comment: Thank you, Adam. I'd stay with ugly=false option for now even in production as it doesn't seem to have great performance impact for my views. Good to know it's known problem.

Comment: FYI: I am getting double rendering with_options without even having haml gem included (Rails 3.0.5).

Comment: probably still broken with erb then as well